# MATLAB graph functions giving strange results

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset for a weighted, undirected graph. I want to know the size of the connected components. After loading the data (which has 3 columns: two representing the vertices that are connected by an edge and the third representing the weight), I do this:

```
G = graph(data(:,1)',data(:,2)');
[bins,binsizes] = conncomp(G);
```

I know for a fact that my graph is not connected, but the largest value in "binsizes" is larger than the total number of nodes in the graph, and the rest are quite small (even though I know that some of the connected components have more than 1000 vertices, the next largest bin size is 21).

Did I do something wrong here? If so, how do I fix it?

**EDIT: here is a sample of the data, but it is about 190000 lines long so I can't post it all...

```
17569 2629 0.045455
17569 3520 0.041667
17569 3535 0.25
17569 4088 0.041667
17569 4318 0.058824
17569 6403 0.33333
17569 7177 0.125
17569 10259 0.066667
17569 10574 0.04
17569 11275 0.038462
17569 11442 0.2
17569 12244 0.038462
17569 12559 0.04
17569 14100 0.076923
17569 14914 0.047619
17569 15266 0.25
17569 15292 0.090909
```

Comment: Hard to follow your text without a specific example... can't you post some example `data` that reproduces the issue?

Comment: The graph command expects nodes to be defined as x,y pairs. It sounds like your nodes are defined as single values ("two columns representing the vertices").

Comment: Is `data` a numeric array? If so, then `graph(data(:,1), data(:,2), data(:,3))` should generate the right graph structure.

Comment: Oh, are your node numbers consecutive? The graph will have `max(data(:,1:2),[],'all')` nodes. So if numbers are skipped in your data, the graph will have an unconnected node for each of them.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ah, that might be it, thanks!